# How can I get the difference between UTC (from my server) and the browser UTC date?

Tags: javascript

Here's what I have tried:

Note that the expirationDate is coming from my server and the nowUtc is coming from the browser. I was hoping they would be the same but it appears they are not.

```
    var now = new Date();
    var nowSecs = now.valueOf();
    var nowUtc = new Date(now.getTime() + (now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
    var nowUtcSecs = nowUtc.valueOf();
    var exp: any = Date.parse(expirationDate);
    var expSecs = exp.valueOf();

    var diffSecs = (expSecs - nowUtcSecs) / 1000;
    var diffMins = diffSecs / 60;
```

When I look in the console this gives me:

```
console.log(expirationDate)
VM2717:1 Fri, 27 Mar 2015 11:11:44 GMT

console.log(nowUtc)
VM2796:1 Fri Mar 27 2015 11:32:42 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)

console.log (diffMins)
VM2943:1 399.0280166666667
```

I was expecting nowUtc to contain the UTC date but it still references the SE Asia Standard time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
var changeDate = new Date('yourdatehere').toISOString();
```

Comment: How does this give me the UTC date? I mean I don't have the 'yourdatehere'.  That is what I am trying to get the browser to give me.

Comment: var now = new Date().toISOString();

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try using Date.UTC() method to find date in UTC format. Here is how it works.

```
{ var utc = new Date(Date.UTC(2000, 10, 5, 0,0,0))}
```

The parameters accepted by Date.UTC are year,month, day, hour, minute, seconds respectively.

For more details refer to  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

Comment: Can you explain how would I get the "2000, 10, 5, 0,0,0". Thanks

Comment: Those are just parameters, store browser date in variable today = new Date(). Then get the year as today.getYear(), month as today.getMonth() and so on.

Comment: arachnid - can you give an example fiddle or plunkr of this as I think your answer if it works okay would be a great help to me and the community.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the documentation for [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now):

> The **Date.now()** method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC

And then [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse):

> The **Date.parse()** method parses a string representation of a date, and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

You would get the difference in seconds between the point in time represented by your string `expirationDate` and the client's clock with:

```
difference = (Date.now() - Date.parse(expirationDate)) / 1000
```

Comment: Somewhat curious as to why this was voted down. It gives the most direct solution to the question asked, as far as I can understand it.